# Share same field data between two different tables?

Tags: database

I have two entities: tbl_Employee and tbl_Salary. 
tbl_Employee contains Employee_ID, Last_Name and First_Name and 
tbl_Salary contains Employee_ID, Number_Of_Lates and Number_Of_Absences.

What I want to happen is that when I add data into the fields of tbl_Employee's Employee_ID, tbl_Salary's Employee_ID would share the same ID. For example, I put ABC123 in the Employee_ID of tbl_Employee then I want it to show in the corresponding field in the tbl_Salary.

I want to do this so that I would practice with Microsoft Access Database. Can someone help? I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You're just talking about a 1:1 join.  It's not typical in simple databases, since it doesn't give you many advantages.

If you want this kind of functionality, you should either just merge your two tables into a single one, or create a VIEW which joins the tables together.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177895(v=office.12).aspx